# (Angular) Ng build not creating an updated project

Tags: angular, build

I searched, but I could not find a solution to this problem. Maybe I'm just doing something very wrong. I have an Angular 7 app, when I build it, it geneates a nicelly built project in /dist. But when I change something for a new release, my build does not change.

Let's say I have a file called 'dashboard', if I just add something like 'TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST.......', it does not display on my new build, but it does when I `ng serve`.. 
What am I doing wrong here? I have to completely reinstall npm to get my new build to work, but that's far to impractical.

Comment: Are you running `ng build` again after the changes to the source code? If yes, what if you delete `dist/` entirely in-between?

Comment: as @jonrsharpe said you need to run `ng build` again and hard refresh the the browser may be some cache issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe even after deleting /dist, the files generated are the exact same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have cache busting.

Either use the prod flag, which contains it :

```
ng build --prod
```

Or explicitly tell it :

```
ng build --output-hashing=all
```

(instead of `all` you can also use `bundles` to hash only the bundles of JS created by your app code, and not all the files like pictures, styles, etc.)